# cannot connect to SERVERXXX\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server-2008

While tring to connet i am getting below error.

Cannot connect to SERVERXXX\SQLEXPRESS.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

i went through the above MS link. it is simply saying that check ur server is running or not?

anybody can help me...?

Comment: Is the service running? What OS is this? More information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect from a remote machine?  If so this is blocked by default.

Is the SQL Service running?

Is the SQL Browser running?

Is the firewall blocking your connection?

Is TCP enabled on the SQL service?

Can you ping the machine?

Can you telnet to the TCP port that the SQL service is listening on?